# failed pre-employment drug screen

Tags: hiring-process

If I test positive for drugs, specifically cocaine in this case, am I then required to be tested xxxx number of times in year one and two following my employment or is that the case only if I am employed and test positive in the safety sensitive arena?

Comment: No idea, depends on the company

Comment: I am confused, isn't drugs of that sort are actually illegal and criminally prosecuted?

Comment: @Strader In the US I don't think they can disclose the results.

Comment: cdl truck driving, safety sensitive work, in pa but that is moot this is a federal law

Comment: Are you asking whether you need to be tested if you didn't get the job or you're no longer working there? If so, who would even care about the results of the test? Or are you asking what happens when you test positive for a drug that can't make you "fail" the overall drug test? Or are you asking what happens when you fail but somehow still get the job (which seems unlikely, because the test is there exactly to not hire people who test positive)?

Comment: @DanielF.Kysor You probably want to delete the Q or/and change your name.

Comment: What makes you think you are even getting hired after testing positive for cocaine?

Answer (score 3):

A pre-employment drug screen is usually not much different than a background check in the sense that if the results are negative (i.e. testing positive for drugs), you likely will not be hired.

Comment: my question is does testing positive to a pre-employment screening mean that when I get hired ......the company has to perform 10 random drug tests in year one and at least 6 in ear two per the federa regs?

Comment: That depends on the company, but most companies will not hire you if you fail the pre-employment drug test.

Comment: I think the use of "negative" is misleading in your answer. A "negative" drug test result means OP passed. As I understand your answer, you're saying if any results from background check or drug test go are negative in the sense they go _against_ OP, then OP will likely not be hired.

Comment: forget if the company hires me or not,   even if i go to another company and I disclose to them which I must tht I tested hot or positive for a drug,  is that company that hires me required to perform 10 drug tests in year one and 6 in year two as would a company if i was working for them and they kept me on?

Comment: @DanielF.Kysor - If you disclose to a Commercial Carrier that you failed a drug test, then you are not going to be hired.  If you know or suspect that you will fail, then your best bet is to skip the test.  Its one thing to miss a pee test, its another to fail it.